# Proper error handling - in javascript/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, error-handling

I am working on Ionic 3 app, that prints bills on bluetooth printer. And I am a little lost, how to properly handle errors in this piece of code:

```
  print(billToPrint){
    return this.bluetoothSerial.list().then((data)=>{
      if(data.length==0) throw new Error("no printer connected");
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data[0]);
      let subscription=this.bluetoothSerial.connect(data[0].address).subscribe(data=>{
        console.log("subscribnuto",data);
        this.bluetoothSerial.write(billToPrint).then((data)=>{
          console.log("data success", data);
        });
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      },err=>{
        throw new Error("Connection to printer failed");
      });
    },err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Whats the proper way to handle errors in this case? I want errors to propagate with concrete error messages, so I can easily handle them in my page(this print method is in service) and show alert with error message. Any ideas? Or is the structure of the code bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of throwing these errors. You can notify them using alert().

```
print(billToPrint){
    return this.bluetoothSerial.list().then((data)=>{
      if(data.length === 0){ Promise.reject(new Error("no printer connected"));}
      // console.log(data);
      // console.log(data[0]);
      let subscription=this.bluetoothSerial.connect(data[0].address).subscribe(data=>{
        if(data){
           // console.log("subscribe",data);
           this.bluetoothSerial.write(billToPrint).then((data)=>{
             // console.log("data success", data);
             Promise.resolve(true);
           });
           subscription.unsubscribe();
        }else{
         Promise.resolve(false);
        }
      },err=>{
        Promise.reject(new Error("Connection to printer failed"));
      });
    },err=>{
      Promise.reject(new Error("error your processing your request"));
    });
  }
```

Comment: thx for answer, but isnt it a bad practice or antipattern to show alerts from provider classes?

Comment: If it is service, you can remove promise resolve/reject with error message. Updated the code.

Comment: Problem with this solution is, that i cant handle the promise rejects in page... even if i use error block and catch block, it says unhandled promise rejection. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't handle using try/catch. promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log("Promise worked");
}, function(err) {
  console.log("Something broke");
});

Comment: I handle it like that in my page :

        this.printService.print(printData).then((data)=>{
          console.log("print hotov");
        }, err=>{
          console.log(err);
          this.showAlert(err.message);
        });

even that doesnt handle it

Comment: When rejecting we need to send as error object. Updated the answer. please have a try.

Comment: It seems that problem is in that this.bluetoothSerial.connect subscription. Whole method is returning Promise from this.bluetoothSerial.list(), but it doesnt wait for result of subscription. So when i call this method from page, it resolves and logs, that print was ok. And then after few seconds, it logs unhandled Error/reject from that failed subscription. But dont know how to solve it.